# Set border of parent <div> depending on 2 child <div>

Tags: html, css

I want a border around a `<div>` with 2 child elements. At the moment the green border is just at the top and not all around the `<div>` container. Can you tell me how to fix this issue?

Here you can see my code:

```css
.frame {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    width: 500px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    min-height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 20px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    min-height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
.entry {
    height: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="entry">
            key
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="entry">
            value
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            value
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            value
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use floats if you don't know how it works.

Comment: Choose an option from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude How do you suggest to create an equal structure ?

Comment: You have tons of techniques, `inline-block`, `flexbox`, `table-cells`, etc. But layout with floats makes you to coding an specific HTML+CSS for that code, turning crazy to change it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.frame` div height become zero as there is no other content apart from the floated div childs, and that's how CSS works. Add this part of code to your `.frame` class

```
.frame{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Using `overflow: hidden;` would create a block formatting context. It would render block boxes in which floats interact with each other.

More at: [**Block formatting context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

Comment: The famous dangerous trick to avoid float craps. The best solution is don't use floats for layouts, only use it to float real floating elements

Comment: However, since this solve the problem, my upvote is for you :)

Comment: To improve your answer, you can tell OP why this is a trick and not a solution, and why the problem solves. You will obtain more upvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your frame doesn't get a height because all the children are floating. You can solve this by adding `overflow: hidden;` to the frame class.

Answer (score 1):

While using `float` on children, don't forget to set layout on parent elements.
There are many ways of setting layouts. For example

```
.frame {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or you can use `:after` pseudo element:

```
.frame:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
.frame {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 20px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
.entry {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="entry">
      key
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="entry">
      value
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
      value
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
      value
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```